# How to shoot tethered using CHDK incompatible Canon Powershot S410?

Tags: canon, remote, tethering, usb, powershot

I have an old Canon powershot S410 compact camera, which I want to use for a time-lapse project. For the project I will need to build an intervalometer to automatically shot photos (probably Arduino based).

CHDK is an obvious approach, but this camera is too old (pre digic II)

This [camera](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/digital_cameras/powershot_s_series/powershot_s410) does not have a normal remote shutter socket, but it does have a USB interface, and I have used Canon software to open the shutter via a windows PC. So I know the camera hardware can activate the shutter via the USB socket.

My question is what is the communication protocol the software used to activate the shutter?

Comment: You're probably going to have to sniff the commands yourself.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi any tools i should be looking at to do that?

Comment: Search Google for a USB sniffer. If you run into problems, I'd suggest that this is a better fit for Stackoverflow rather than this site.

Answer (score 1):

Usually Cannon uses Picture Transfer Protocol (PTP) and Media Transfer Protocol (MTP)  but I'm not sure you can control your powershot with them.  Have a look to [Gphoto](http://gphoto.org/doc/remote/) maybe someone has already done the work. The simplest way with your Arduino is to "push" the shot button with an external device a "meccanic finger" or if you don't care about your camera opening it and find the way to hack the "shot button" circuit.

P.S. You can build a simple intervalometer with some resistors, and a relay/capacitor circuit or with a PUT/capacitor circuit maybe you can integrate it with your camera to make the system more portable.